# How to parse/grab/get one source line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I would like to get the value of one line of the HTML source.

Here is a part of the code :

```
<body><div><span>Hello</span></div>
<p class="selected">Hello Again</p>
<p>And Again</p>

  <td class="first">
    <input type="checkbox" name="mainForm:tableEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE:5:j_idt164" onclick="clickCheck(this, 'EPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE');"/>

  <input type="hidden" name="trdataEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE" value="CED$$PAL$$" />
 </td>
<td><a href="#" onclick="mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById('mainForm'),{'mainForm:tableEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE:5:j_idt172':'mainForm:tableEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE:5:j_idt172'},'');return false">
  <label>
CED</label>
  </a>
</td>
<textarea id="messages"></textarea> <!--print the result for my test-->

<script>
    var x = $("input:contains('CED')").prev(); //my jquery test to get the line
    $( "#messages" ).val(x); //sending the result to be shown in the html page
</script>

</body>
```

I aim to have the previous line that contains 'CED' in the variable 'x'.
So, i want `x = "input type=checkbox name="mainForm:tableEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE:5:j_idt164" onclick="clickCheck(this, 'EPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE');"/>"`

And, in the end, `x = mainForm:tableEPS_PORTEFEUILLE_SITE:5:j_idt164`

So, to achieve this, i use jquery in casperjs :

```
var x = $("input:contains('CED')").prev(); 
$( "#messages" ).val(x);
```

I guess that var x definition is correct, but i don't find the way to store the line.

So my question is :

- What should i put after prev() ?
- And, is .val(x) correct?

For Linux users, it is like `x = awk -F'"' {print $3}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with

```
this.evaluate (function() { return $("input[value='CED$$PAL$$']").prev().click()});
```

Comment: I don't see why you added the `click`. Why would this work? You need `$("input[value='CED$$PAL$$']").prev().attr("name")`.